# Copy and paste non blank cell values from one sheet to another sheet

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to copy paste non blank cells in one sheet to other using below code

```
Public Sub Copypastenonblanks()
Dim mySheet As Worksheet, myOtherSheet As Worksheet, myBook As Workbook 
Set myBook = Excel.ActiveWorkbook
Set mySheet = myBook.Sheets("Sheet1")
Set myOtherSheet = myBook.Sheets("Sheet2")
mySheet.Range("BK1:BK230").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants).Copy myOtherSheet.Range
("Q2")
End Sub
```

In the sheet column BK contains blank cells, and i'm trying to copy non blanks and
 paste to othersheet , it pastes only Heading ,not all data.

Comment: Not sure what you mean, it works fine for me using Excel 2010.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function does work for me in Excel 2013. However, when built-in functions don't produce the expected results, you can **always** turn around and build your own custom made function (which most of the time, isn't hard at all).

Here's how I'd do it :

```
Sub CopyPasteNonBlanks()

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
    Set ws1 = wb.Sheets(1)
    Set ws2 = wb.Sheets(2)

    col1 = 63 'Column BK of 1st sheet
    col2 = 17 'Column Q of 2nd sheet

    lastRow1 = ws1.Cells(ws1.Rows.Count, col1).End(xlUp).Row 'Find last row of 1st sheet
    currentRow2 = 2 'Start below headers of 2nd sheet

    For iRow1 = 1 To lastRow1

        If ws1.Cells(iRow1, col1) <> "" Then

            ws2.Cells(currentRow2, col2) = ws1.Cells(iRow1, col1)
            currentRow2 = currentRow2 + 1

        End If

    Next iRow1

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do what you need.

```
Public Sub Copypastenonblanks()

Dim mySheet As Worksheet
Dim myOtherSheet As Worksheet
Dim myBook As Workbook
Dim irow As Integer
Dim c As Variant

Set myBook = Excel.ThisWorkbook
Set mySheet = myBook.Sheets("Sheet1")
Set myOtherSheet = myBook.Sheets("Sheet2")

irow = 0

Do Until irow = -1
    For Each c In mySheet.Range("BK1:BK230")
        irow = irow + 1

        If c.Value <> "" Then
            myOtherSheet.Cells(irow, 17).Value = c.Value
        Else
            If irow = 230 Then
                irow = -1
            End If
            irow = irow - 1
            GoTo EndofNext
        End If

        If irow = 230 Then
            irow = -1
        End If
EndofNext:
        Next c
    Loop
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

If your goal is actually to copy all non blank cells - not only constants - try and replace your

```
mySheet.Range("BK1:BK230").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants).Copy _
myOtherSheet.Range("Q2")
```

line with something like

```
With mySheet.Range("BK1:BK230")
    Union(.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants), .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas)). _
    Copy myOtherSheet.Range("Q2")
End With
```